# Help on identifying encryption/encoding scheme

Tags: encryption, encodings, unknown-data

I am trying to find the encryption used in a legacy database.
The db is from 2003, and it is stored on a dbf (FoxPro) file.

The following are supposed to be ZIP numbers, more specifically, are supposed to be  comprising of 5 numerical digits.

(ascii hex)

```
2G-Zwm  \0x32\0x47\0x2d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
&'MZwm  \0x26\0x27\0x4d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
6W-Zwm  \0x36\0x57\0x2d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
2'=Zwm  \0x32\0x27\0x3d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
*']Zwm  \0x2a\0x27\0x5d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
GMZwm  \0x1e\0x47\0x4d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
/}Zwm  \0x1a\0x2f\0x7d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
*G=Zwm  \0x2a\0x47\0x3d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
6WMZwm  \0x36\0x57\0x4d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
6_wm  \0x36\0x5f\0x77\0x6d
?Zwm  \0x12\0x3f\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
27MZwm  \0x32\0x37\0x4d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
/Zwm  \0x12\0x2f\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
*gwm  \0x2a\0x67\0x77\0x6d
"_-Zwm  \0x22\0x5f\0x2d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
7}Zwm  \0x1e\0x37\0x7d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
&?=Zwm  \0x26\0x3f\0x3d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
"'=Zwm  \0x22\0x27\0x3d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
OMZwm  \0x1e\0x4f\0x4d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
?]Zwm  \0x1e\0x3f\0x5d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
./=Zwm  \0x2e\0x2f\0x3d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
*WMZwm  \0x2a\0x57\0x4d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
&7}Zwm  \0x26\0x37\0x7d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
2?}Zwm  \0x32\0x3f\0x7d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
*?}Zwm  \0x2a\0x3f\0x7d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
"/mZwm  \0x22\0x2f\0x6d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
*-Zwm  \0x2a\0x1f\0x2d\0x5a\0x77\0x6d
```

In the database description, there is  ascii "3" (\0x33) as a possible password or something (it follows the database description column).

The ciphertexts are repeated on the DB with a reasonable frequency  for ZIP codes suggesting that the encryption is on each ZIP code

The list is longer and there are values where the ciphertext DOES NOT ends in Zwm, but these values (not ending in Zwm) seem to be noise (could be the result of spaces on the original text) since they occur very infrequently.

```
.gZwm,19477
6gZwm,12815
2OZwm,8421
&gZwm,8168
.O}Zwm,4065
*GZwm,16516
v_Zwm,1
e,3
z*-[^,1
ti,2
2'lm,2
jYpe,1
2/-Zwm,1
^8m,1
v,1
Xpm,1
R2/m,1
wm,2
X,1
6-wU^,1
6gw\,1
6gZez,1
6gm8wm,1
]Xse,1
jD-b,1
vl,3
BO-8wm,1
jX,1
:vg8sa,1
jsc,1
```

The usual suspect (XOR) does not seem to be of any use (i have tried to char wise XOR with both \0x03 and \0x33)

Any hints on what encryption is used?